# "Remotely closed" when I try to send REST with HTTPS in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have a simple REST HTTPS GET, the uri of it is like that:

https://mytest.test:443/nccpointshop/REST/giftcard/giftcards/list/currency/SEK

which works perfectly to run in a browser, Postman, etc. With Mule 3.8 HTTP I select the uri from the RAML generataed specification, set uri-param and still I am getting an exception :

```html
DEBUG 2016-06-28 16:38:35,321 [[svc0014_loyalty].http.requester.ODP_Request_Configuration(1) SelectorRunner] com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.AsyncHttpClientFilter: REQUEST: HttpRequestPacket (
   method=GET
   url=/nccpointshop/REST/giftcard/giftcards/list/currency/SEK
   query=null
   protocol=HTTP/1.1
   content-length=-1
   headers=[
      Host=correct.host:443
      User-Agent=AHC/1.0
      Connection=keep-alive
      Accept=*/*]
)
DEBUG 2016-06-28 16:38:35,322 [[svc0014_loyalty].http.requester.ODP_Request_Configuration(1) SelectorRunner] org.mule.module.http.internal.HttpMessageLogger: REQUESTER
GET /nccpointshop/REST/giftcard/giftcards/list/currency/SEK HTTP/1.1
Host: correct.host:443
User-Agent: AHC/1.0
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*


DEBUG 2016-06-28 16:38:35,498 [[svc0014_loyalty].http.requester.ODP_Request_Configuration.worker(8)] com.ning.http.client.AsyncCompletionHandlerBase: Remotely closed
java.io.IOException: Remotely closed
DEBUG 2016-06-28 16:38:35,520 [[svc0014_loyalty].svc0014_loyalty-httpListenerConfig.worker.02] com.mulesoft.mule.debugger.server.DebuggerMuleNotificationHandlerImpl: MESSAGE_PROCESSOR_POST_INVOKE -> Path /get:\/giftcards:svc0014_loyalty-config/processors/2
DEBUG 2016-06-28 16:38:37,327 [[svc0014_loyalty].Mule.01] com.mulesoft.mule.debugger.server.DebuggerMuleNotificationHandlerImpl: Notification 2001 was received ef4625b0-3d3d-11e6-998f-448500a727fa
ERROR 2016-06-28 16:38:37,329 [[svc0014_loyalty].svc0014_loyalty-httpListenerConfig.worker.02] org.mule.module.apikit.MappingExceptionListener: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-29999
Payload               : {NullPayload}
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. Remotely closed (java.io.IOException)
2. java.io.IOException: Remotely closed (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync:349 (null)
3. java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Remotely closed (java.io.IOException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient:245 (null)
4. Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester:287 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.IOException: Remotely closed

********************************************************************************
```

I am attaching a picture of how my configuration looks like

[image]

Comment: Can you please show your socket config details

Comment: Try to increase the timeout or KeepAlive= active?

Comment: You state that you have the problem when you call the REST URL after you've generated flows using a RAML file. If that's the case your HTTPS connector config should show something like e.g. /api/v1/* because it's common to all flows. The path to your currency GET with the {currency} URI parameter doesn't make sense to me. Did you generate your flows using a RAML file? If so, show us the RAML section for the GET currency section.

Comment: Can you please share the HTTPS_Request_Configuration?

Comment: Ok, here comes the HTTPS_Request_config:  <http:request-config name="ODP_Request_Configuration" host="${odp.ws.uri}" port="${odp.ws.port}" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" basePath="${odp.rest.baseUri}" protocol="HTTPS" />

Comment: I found out what the problem is. Mule always adds the port, but the backend system resolves the HTTPS request with host only to a port different than the default of 443. Is there a way to say that this is tell HTTP connector to not add port?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing with Mule HTTP connector is that it adds host and port from the associated configuration always as a header:
 headers=[
      Host=correct.host:443

Some systems do not allow that, they do not accept adding the port (in our case the port is dynamically allocated in the backend system).
So, this request: https://correct.host:443/nccpointshop/REST/giftcard/giftcards/list/currency/SEK

is invalid, but this one is valid:
https://correct.host/nccpointshop/REST/giftcard/giftcards/list/currency/SEK

This is hard to notice and catch, as Postman and Chrome will both send correct requests. I recommend using some other tool like SoapUI (I noticed it with it).
However, there is a way to overwrite the value for the "Host" in the headers like this:

```
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration1" path="/nccpointshop/REST/giftcard/giftcards/list/currency/SEK" method="GET" doc:name="Copy_of_HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="Host" value="correct.host"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
```

Comment: It works! You are my saviour!